# Filtering for email address with a dot

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to filter only the email with dot (Sam.Smith@forfun.com). But all email would be displayed to me. Is this somehow possible to get only "Sam.Smith@forfun.com" this?

```
PS C:\Users\Rayman>  Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam".AlternateEmailAddresses
PS C:\Users\Rayman>  (Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam Smith").UserPrincipalName
PS C:\Users\Rayman> Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam Smith" | Select Mail
Sam.Smith@forfun.com
samsmith@forfun.com
```

I have tried many variants without success.

Comment: Does "sam.smith" not work? You can also grab the first one using `Select-Object` or, if it's returning an array, you can just select the first one using the index number: `(Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam Smith"| Select Mail)[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Abraham Zinala for your suggestion posting this as solution to help other community member if they encounter for same requirement.

**`Note : Use PowerShell Version 7+ Version.`**

PowerShell Script :

```
(Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam Smith"| Select Mail)[0]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select-Object -First 1` to discard everything but the first output item:

```
$samSmith = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Sam Smith" |Select-Object -First 1
```